# Java referencing an ArrayList from method outside of main method

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have the following array list:

```
ArrayList <Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
```

In my main method I create instances of them

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     Employee test = new Manager("john doe", 1000); //manager is subclass

}
```

I have a method that checks that the employee object doesn't already exist, the equals method is defined in the subclasses

```
public void addEmployee(Employee newEmployee){
    for (int i  = 0; i < employees.size(); i++){
           if(newEmployee.equals(employees.get(i))){
               .........
           }
       }
 }
```

Theres more to it above, but you get the point. I need to reference the ArrayList, but if I instantiate the array list outside of the main method I can't add any variables to it, getting the error "non-static method cannot be referenced from static context" which makes sense, but I don't know how to use that method then since I can't declare it in the main method.

Comment: Declare it as a `static` variable. What's the issue?

Comment: How are these three segments of code even related?  It's not clear what you're trying to do or what's preventing you.

Comment: declare the test variable as static? I do that and I get an error saying illegal start of expression

Comment: @David it's a watered down version of all my code. I have a main superclass of employee, a subclass of manager, and subclass of worker, then this main class that tests the methods and constructors and such.

Comment: seems like a Set would be a more suitable container than an ArrayList

Comment: @Burninrock24 I think people are downvoting you because they view it as a "dumb question". Personally, I find it fine enough, and gave it an upvote. However, in future I suggest you try to do some more research into the problem, tell us what you've tried, where you've searched, etc.

Comment: It's easy to know what to search for in retrospect, but I had no idea what was wrong beyond the error message, and none of the examples I found online involved an ArrayList. I wasn't aware that an ArrayList could still function while being declared static. But I guess this just means that I don't know the implications of something being static in the first place. Oh well, downvote away I gues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to create a class for managing employee's you'll want to make your method and collection static

```
static ArrayList <Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

public static void addEmployee(Employee newEmployee){
    for (int i  = 0; i < employees.size(); i++){
           if(newEmployee.equals(employees.get(i))){
               .........
           }
       }
 }
```

@muued has a point.  There are other data structures in java then ArrayList.  When in doubt I look at this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that I could declare ArrayList as static like that and still allow it to have it's elements be modified and still function properly.

Comment: @BoristheSpider deserves the credit for that. He spotted it first.

Comment: I'm new to this place is there a way to give him the best answer?

Comment: He didn't post an answer but his comment can be upvoted.